# Goclipse workspace for golang vs other languages

Tags: eclipse, go, goclipse

I have code in /home/user/Documents/code/workspace/ (Debian Jessie) in subfolders like java/ for java and python/ for python I've written. For golang in Eclipse, should I use the workspace ~/Documents/code/workspace or ../workspace/go or ../workspace/go/src?

Comment: What I do is to have a workspace under my `workspaces` folder and put the  actual projects under `$GOPATH/src`

Answer (score 1):

Use workspace/go as your workspace. From [code organization guidelines](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) on golang.org

> Go code must be kept inside a workspace. A workspace is a directory
>   hierarchy with three directories at its root:
>
> - src contains Go source files organized into packages (one package per    directory),
> - pkg contains package objects, and
> - bin contains executable    commands.
>
> The go tool builds source packages and installs the resulting binaries
>   to the pkg and bin directories.
>
> The src subdirectory typically contains multiple version control
>   repositories (such as for Git or Mercurial) that track the development
>   of one or more source packages.

Comment: Okay, but when I use Goclipse to start a new go project, it tries to put it in ../workspace/go/newprojectname as the default location, should I specify ../workspace/go/src/newprojectname since if I run `go get github.com/whatever` it puts it in ../workspace/go/src/github.com/whatever?

Comment: okay, I used ../workspace/go/src/somename/ for the default location under Goclipse, and it seems to work. Thanks.